# Conditionally fill dataframe series rows with values from corresponding series

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe like this:

```
   values values2 newrow
1  10     2
2  24     3
3  56     1
4  -10    2
5  1      0
6  78     1
7 -1      0
```

I would like to select only dataframe["values"] with positive values and add to the corresponding newrow the values from series values2

expected result

```
   values values2 newrow
1  10     2       2
2  24     3       3
3  56     1       1
4  -10    2       empty
5  1      0       0
6  78     1       1
7 -1      0       empty
```

what i achieved so far is

```
dataframe.loc[dataframe['values'], 'newrow'] = i would like here to put dataframevalue['values2'] but it's not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where`:

```py
df["newrow"] = np.where(df["values"] > 0, df["values2"], "empty")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   values  values2 newrow
0      10        2      2
1      24        3      3
2      56        1      1
3     -10        2  empty
4       1        0      0
5      78        1      1
6      -1        0  empty
```